# Using CLT to get Confidence Interval for Mean in MA(1)

Tags: time-series, self-study, confidence-interval, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

Self-study:

Let $$X_t = \mu + a_t + \theta a_{t-1}$$

$a_t$ is white noise with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$.

Given $\bar x = c$ for a sample size of 100. Find confidence interval for $\mu$.

My attempt: Since the distribution of disturbance term is not given, CLT will be required.

From Wiki I found that the one of the CLT for dependent processes require the condition of stationarity and strong mixing. The above process is stationary but how do I check for strong mixing? The autocorrelation is zero after one lag so after short enough distance the subsequences are uncorrelated but not necessarily independent. Is this even right thinking?

The other CLT on wiki was defined for Martingales. Given my lack of detailed knowledge, it is taxing to read about all possibilities. What might be the simplest way to use CLT here?

(How come we do not have a tag for mixing?)

Comment: Since it's an MA(1) , the disturbance terms are the $a_t$ and  they can be considered to be normal with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$. I don't think you need the CLT for the question but I don't see how to get an answer without being able to estimate $\sigma^2$ ? Hopefully someone else has a better insight.

Comment: @mlofton: How can they be considered normal? Under normality I can bring in LRV and solve easily but stuck because the distribution of disturbance term is not given.

Comment: Also assume $\sigma$ is given. So you can find answer in terms of Sigma...no need to estimate.

Comment: @Dayne You need to put $\boldsymbol{x} = (X_1, \cdots, X_{100})^{\prime}$ in a vector and find its multivariate normal distribution to express the dependencies.  Have you been working with only the marginal distributions?  For instance $\boldsymbol{x} \sim N( \mu \boldsymbol{1}_{100}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$, where $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ denotes the MA(1) variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: @Dayne: When you state that $a_{t}$ is white noise with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, white noise, in the time series terminology, usually is synonymous with normality. I don't know what LRV stands for but what uset277126 suggested sounds reasonable. The only question I have with that suggested approach is how to obtain an estimate of $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @mlofton: I don't think white noise is synonymous with normality. Could you give some references to substantiate this?

Comment: @user277126: Once again why normality?

Comment: Hi Dayne: I'm only claiming that white noise tends to be synonymous with normality in the time series literature. In general, you are correct that it's not. I'll try to find some reference but I may not be able to. One heuristic argument would be the following:

Comment: continued WN in the dsp world means that all frequencies in the corresponding fourier transform of the WN series have the same energy. This is similar to saying that a WN signal is perfectly random.  Now, given the mean $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of a distribution, the normal distribution is known to maximize the entropy of the distribution. So, normality maximizes randomness in the same way that white noise is maximal randomness. It's not a real proof but it's an argument.  When I have time, I'll look around but, in general, the random terms of any MA(k) are always assumed to be normal.

Comment: @Dayne: Below is a cross validated explanation of white noise.  Based on that, I think one can say that I'm wrong to say that normality and white noise are the same thing, even in time series analysis. But the $a_t$ in your MA model are generally assumed to be normal. That I'm certain about.  You can confirm that by checking out the Box-Jenkins text,  Abraham-Ledollter's text or Hamilton's "Time Series Analysis".   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309719/white-noise-in-statistics